# Lotus Notes handling mailto links from HTML formated emails

Tags: mailto, lotus

I am sending emails to different users in my corporation.  Some of our clients use Lotus Notes (8).
These emails are generated by the server.  Inside this email (HTML formatted), there is a link to a "mailto":

```
Please <a href="mailto:myaddress@mycorp.ca" >click here</a> to reply.
```

There is nothing else in the body of the email.
Unfortunatly, when I click on this link (wich does appear as a link when reading the email from a Lotus Notes client), I get this error:

```
\\mailto:myaddress@mycorp.ca is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this
network ressource.  Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access
permissions.

The parameter is incorrect.
```

On the other hand, if I create the email manually through the Notes client (using a "HotSpot"), the link works...  Unfortunatly, generating the email with the Lotus Notes API is not a possibility because (a) we do not have a Domino server in our corporation, and (b) not all of our users use Lotus Notes...

Question: Is there a way to fix this problem without using the Lotus Notes API?
I have tried this :

```
<div onclick="window.navigate('mailto:myaddress@mycorp.ca');" >Click Here</div>
```

but the javascript code is ignored...  (probably a javascript security restriction in the client).

I have also considered not using HTML format in my emails; I could do most of my formatting using Rich Text Format, but I do not know what syntaxt would generate a Hotspot (or a functional mailto link) in the RTF content...

Comment: It is also woth noting that the link in question works with all other email clients...

Comment: If you examine an email generated by Lotus Notes, does anything in it give you a hint as to how to create an email link which will work with it?

Comment: That's the problem.  When i generate an email with Lotus Notes, there doesn't seem to be a way to "examine" the content itself (in plain text).  When I receive an HTML formatted email from another client, there is an option to "View Source", but that option is greyed-out when I get an email from Lotus Notes (or even while creating the email in Notes)...

Comment: If you can drag an email onto the desktop then you can examine it with a text editor (or hex editor). Otherwise, trying to find out what is inside the email could be horribly complicated: [Lotus Notes - save whole email message eml c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452468/lotus-notes-save-whole-email-message-eml-c-sharp). Or you could brute-force it by using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to look at the raw data as it comes over the wire.

Comment: Probably not all that helpful, but instead of getting `\\mailto:myaddress@mycorp.ca is not accessible.` on my machine, it will open up in Outlook, even though Notes is my configured default email client.

Comment: [This article](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2012/10/open-mailtolinks-lotus-notes-or-outlook.html) allowed me to open the mailto in Notes.

Comment: Just a wild idea, but have you tried `mailto://myaddress@mycorp.ca`? I know the URL is not correct, but I'll give it a try, just in case it works...

Comment: What the hell???  Xavier just found my answer!  It's not perfect (it opens a blank IE page (imbedded or not) and leaves it open, but at the very least the mailto protocol is fired!  Thank you!  I would like to award the bounty to you Xavier Rubio Jansana!  (Can you write your last comment as an answer and I will award you the bounty!)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a way for one link that will work for both clients - Outlook and Lotus.

Lotus Notes developers call it HotSpot.

Check those links, if you can create it manually - send it to yourself and check the sent HTML.

http://blog.iangoodsell.com/2009/06/i-hate-lotus-notes-inserting-hyperlinks.html

http://www.alanlepofsky.net/alepofsky/alanblog.nsf/dx/creating-links-to-a-web-page

Comment: Ya, but like I said, I am generating these things from a server engine and do not have access to what is required to use the Notes API.

Comment: I would try to do it manually first and then just copy paste it. Try to send it to your private email. No need to use API.

Comment: I will try that too.  I think (untested) that the Domino server actually "converts" the email to HTML (or rich text) when it is going out, which would mean that if I send it out, then back in, the HotSpot would no longer work as a HotSpot, but would be converted to a standard HTML link, and would behave accordingly once it is back in Lotus Notes.  But this is definitely worth a try.  Thanks.  (I should mention that Xavier's comment is the answer though.  Although not perfect, at least the URL protocol is fired...  But if this solution is better, I will let us all know for sure!)